# CPU Spiking on Web App

Tags: web-applications, cpu-usage

A user's CPU is running to 50% CPU when navigating to my web app.

I have very high confidence that this issue is particular to the user.

Besides running a profiler on this user's browser, checking for style and javascript functions' CPU usage, what steps would you take to evaluate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a profiler in the user's browser should give some visibility into what's going on.

However, before profiling I would suggest trying something simpler to confirm that the problem is with the user's environment.

There are couple of simple tests to try that may help identify the problem.

One is to ask someone else with a similary equipped machine to do the same thing using the same version of the browser.

The other one is to try using a different browser on the same machine and see if the same behavior is observed.

If cpu usage on different systems is similar, it may be an app issue. If two different browsers on the same machine behave very differently, then you may have hit upon a browser anomaly.

Comment: The user is having this problem on IE8 on both his laptop and a workstation. Tomorrow I'll meet with him and control his screen to profile. Good tip on Firefox (or other browser). I'll try that out.